# Measure on the places of $\bar{\mathbb Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, measure-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Consider the set $S$ of all places of $\mathbb Q$ (i.e. the set of all absolute values up to equivalence). Then we can consider $S$ as a measure space with the counting measure $\mu$. Therefore $\mu(\{s\})=1$ for any $s\in S$.

Now let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ and let $S_K$ be the set of places of $K$. Then the restriction of absolute values gives a map:

$$f_{K|\mathbb Q}: S_K\to S$$

that has finite fibres. In general the pullback measure doesn't exist, but it is a well known fact that when we have a ``fiberwise integration'' (like in the case of our $f_{K|\mathbb Q}$), then we have a pullback measure. Therefore we endow $S_K$ with the measure $\mu_K:=\mu^\ast$ that should be a sort of weighted counting measure. For instance if $f^{-1}_{K|\mathbb Q}(s)=\{t_1,\ldots, t_n\}$, I suppose that $\mu_K(t_i)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Now consider the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb Q}$ and the set of all its places $\bar{S}$. I suppose that by generalising the above argument I can obtain a measure space $(\bar{S},\nu)$ as a projective limit of the measure spaces $\{(K,\mu_K)\}_{[K:\mathbb Q]<\infty}$.

Now the question:

> How does the measure $\nu$ look like? Is it again some sort of generalised counting measure? Maybe not because I don't even know if $\bar{S}$ is countable. I am having troubles trying to understand what is the measure of a
> singleton in $\bar{S}$.

Comment: First of all, you can split the space into the components given by the rational primes $p$. Over each prime, the set $S(p)$ of places above $p$ is a projective limit of finite sets, the finite sets being the places over $p$ of a given number field. Now your measure is the equidistributive measure of this projective limit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will work on it, but I have a silly question (forgive me for my ignorance): what do you mean by "equidistributive measure"? Can you add some details, plaese?

Comment: I don't know about projective limits of measures, but my guess is that the question is: Do you expect any set to be measurable not coming from a preimage of a finite set over a finite extension?

Comment: The Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q$ acts transitively on the set of valuations over p. This group is a profinite group and its Haar-measure does the job.